# How do I remove many vertices from a surface mesh in CGAL?

Tags: c++, cgal

I'm trying to iterate over all the vertices in a surface mesh and remove those vertices that satisfy certain criteria. The removal of the vertex should remove the connected faces.

CGAL::Euler::remove_center_vertex seems to do what I hoped but it invalidates the iterator so how should I remove many vertices from a surface mesh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to have a look at the simplification package:
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_simplification/index.html

**EDIT:**
You should first collect all the vertices you want to remove and then do all the calls to `remove_center_vertex()` using the collected vertices. Alternatively you might to have a look at the function [`remove_connected_components()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__keep__connected__components__grp.html#ga4b7d6fb132789998695d855f326a0fba). Collect the set of faces incident to the vertices to be removed and call that function to remove all the faces at once. Note that you might have to call [`expand_face_selection_for_removal()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLSelectionFct.html#ga6f8d338df28c24bbf93677f24f7bcbbe) to prevent the creation of non-manifold vertices.

Comment: I'm not trying to simplify - I want to leave a hole. I want to remove a section of my mesh completely.